# An algorithum question about assigning roles to players

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Assume there is a game, it has n players and m roles(n<=m). Each player lists his favourite roles (can be one or more). Record this information as a 2d array of boolean, namely A, where A[i][j] means whether j-th role is i-th player's favourite. The question is, how to write a function that inputs A, and returns a boolean, such that the following conditions hold: Each role can be assigned to at most one player; Each player must have exactly one role and it must be one of his favourite. If there is a way to assign roles to players, the function should return true, otherwise false.

The brute force way to do it is to iterate all possible combinations of assignments, which results in O(P(m,n)) time complexity. Is there a polynomial time algorithm that solves this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can solve this in O(nm) in Graph Theory, as a [Maximum Bipartite Matching](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/) : You transform the problem into a network flow one, and apply [Ford-Fulkerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) algorithm to it. If the maximum flow is n, then you can assign a favourite role to each player, otherwise there is none such assignation.

To make the network flow problem, you make a graph with :

- a source Node
- a Node for every player
- a Node for every role
- a sink Node

We then connect these node with the following directed edges, with capacity 1 :

- an Edge from the source to every player Node
- an Edge from every role Node to the sink
- an Edge from player Node i to role Node j if role j is a favourite of player i (i.e. A[i][j] is true)

The goal is to find the maximum flow that can pass from the source to the sink.
As the edges have a capacity of 1, we have a maximum flow of N only if the flow pass through each player, and each role can only be assigned once, as they connect to the sink with a capacity of one.

The first link is really helpfull to understand and implement the algorithm

Feel free to ask for clarifications or point mistakes